# Check if input field has a value to toggle some classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I got an input field in my meteor-app and I want to check if there is some content, because the position of the input field depends on wether there is an input value or not. If the user begins typing (min. one character), the input field moves to the top of the page.

In my current solution I'm looking for a keyup event to check if there is a value. If there is a value, a class will be added and another one is removed.
If the input field is empty, it is just the other way round.

```
Template.search.events({
    'keyup input': function(event, template) {
        if (event.target.value.length) {
            $('#wrapper').addClass('top');
            $('#result').removeClass('hide');
        }
        else {
            $('#wrapper').removeClass('top');
            $('#result').addClass('hide');
        }
    }
});
```

**My problems**

1) I think that the keyup event not the best way as the user could paste some content or cut it.

2) If the user types 'anything', classes will be changed 8 times - although you don't see that, but it is quite bad coding, isn't it?

3) If I could avoid that multiple looping, I could use a toggleClass...

PS: Maybe it is useful to save some informations in a session var? (I'm just brainstorming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle cut and paste operations in your field *without* requiring the field to lose focus, use the `input` event. You can also use jQuery's `toggleClass` to simplify your code:

```
Template.search.events({
    'input input': function(event, template) { // first input is the event, second is the object
        var hasContent = event.target.value.length > 0;
        $('#wrapper').toggleClass('top',hasContent);
        $('#result').toggleClass('hide',!hasContent);
    }
});
```

Comment: To add onto this, if you do not want the event to fire every time a user presses a button you can use the `lodash` or `underscore` `debounce` method with `leadingEdge` or `immediate` set to true respectively.